# How to embed multiple tags in Rails routes, like Stack Overflow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, tags

When one selects a tag on Stack Overflow, it is added to the end of the URL.  Add a second tag and it is added to the end of the URL after the first Tag, with a `+` delimiter.  For example:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails+best-practices
```

How is this implemented?  Is this a routing enhancement or some logic contained in the `TagsController`?  Finally, how does one 'extract' these tags for filtering (assuming that they are not in the `params[]` array)?

Answer (score 1):

Vojto's answer is correct, but note that you can also use Route Globbing on the server side to handle this cleanly. A route defined as `/:controller/*tags` will match `/questions/ruby/rails/routing`, and in the `questions_controller`, `params[:tags]` will be an array containing `['ruby','rails','routing']`. See the [Routing docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Routing.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think Rails doesn't mind if params contains symbols like `+`. That means, you can access all tags as one argument, create a route like: `'/show/:tags'`

Then you can access `params[:tags]`, which will be string like `'ruby+rails'`. You can simply do `'ruby+rails'.split('+')` to turn it into an array.

By that you can easily append new tag to this array, and turn it back into string with `my_array_with_tags.join('+')`.