# has_many :through association in the url/view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I added a `has_many :through` association (join table) to my houses model, so a house can have multiply categories such as "lastminute", "house with pool" etc.

I made a custom query, so by example I want all the house in the "lastminute" category (5)

```
@lastminutes = House.find(:all, :select=>"houses.*", :joins=>"JOIN category_join_tables ON houses.id = category_join_tables.house_id", :conditions=>["category_join_tables.house_id = houses.id AND category_join_tables.category_id = ?", 5])
```

This work fine in the console.

What is the best approach to get this working on my site. I want url stucture likes this:

```
domain.com/locale/holidayhouses/lastminutes (house in the lastminute category)
domain.com/locale/holidayhouses/holidayhouses_with_pool (houses in the pool category)

domain.com/locale/lastminutes (houses and appartments in the lastminute category)
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite easy:

config/routes.rb:

```
match 'search/*categories' => "controller#action"
```

In your action you get now the categories as an array and only need to parse them into the query. I guess you need the "search" because otherwise rails will take every normal request as categories and redirect you to the action.

see [How to embed multiple tags in Rails routes, like Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539819/how-to-embed-multiple-tags-in-rails-routes-like-stack-overflow)

---

For the l18n part you can do it like

```
scope "/:locale" do
  # move all the other routes in here to work with the locale
end
```

check out the [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-the-url-params) on I18N